# My Discord.js Bot welcome message suddenly stopped working

Tags: javascript, discord.js

so I made a Discord bot, the welcome message was working for the first 3 months or so but suddenly it stopped working, can I asks why? I had been searching as to why it does not work but I couldn't find why. Thank You before.

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    const channel = member.guild.channels.find(
        ch => ch.name === '•chat-kalem•'
    );

    const redirch = member.guild.channel.cache.find(ch => ch.name === "•rules•");

    channel.send(`Welcome, ${member}! Please read the ${redirch} first.`);
});
```

Comment: Did you update your `package.json` dependencies for `discord.js`? Looks like it was reported as an issue a few months ago: [GitHub Issue #4949](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/issues/4949). Maybe you should re-verify your bot? Also, possibly update to version 12?

Comment: How do I update my `package.json` ? I think I have updated my `discord.js` to the latest version.

Comment: Already tried updating `discord.js`, still not working

Comment: Read the GitHub issue linked in my previous comment. Use that to troubleshoot.

Comment: Oh, turns out there are some kind of error happens at the code, I don't know what but when I rewrite them it works again. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey there your issue is because of recent gateway changes of the Discord Api that you need to enable the intents here is a fix for you -

- Head over to [Discord Developers Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications/)
- Choose your application
- Inside the `bot` section if yiu scroll a little bit down , you will see a section named `Privileged Gateway Intents`
- Enable the `SERVER MEMBERS INTENT` and restart the bot and your bot will start recieving the `guildMemberAdd` event!

Learn more about intents at [Discord.js](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html)